# iTunes Submission Warning

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am getting a list of missing icons when uploading binary to Apple store. I have already added these missing icons by selecting the project icon --> General --> Selected the required icon file. I have already added these icon files to my project. After that I performed clean and Archive. How can we remove this warning message?

[image: Warning message when uploading to Apple store]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pure 'png' format for your icon.

Answer (score 0):

I was using correct icon files and dimensions but was still facing the issue. Finally I resolved it. Below are the steps:

Step 1: Select your project icon in Xcode.

Step 2: Go to 'General' tab.

Step 3: Expand the 'Launch Images' tab.

Step 4: Click on 'Use Asset Catalog'.

Step 5: Follow the steps on the dialog.

Step 6: Clean the target and Archive.

Step 7: Validate your Archive before submitting it to Apple Store.

This works for me. Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings only comes when you are trying to give support to iOS 7 with out porting your project to Xcode 5 . Cause there two type of images only requires in iOS 7 . So I suggest integrate icon with mentioned two sizes in the warning and also mention them in your pList file like this .[image]